# Commutative Noetherian Domains of Krull Dimension One

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

k is an alegraically closed field and A is a commutative k-algebra. We also know that A is a Noetherian domain and its Krull dimension is one. Are there any necessary and sufficient conditions on A under which A becomes finitely generated module over a polynomial algebra k[c] for some c in A? Does anybody know any papers or books that discuss this? 
Thanks guys.

Comment: The answer seems to be that it is necessary and sufficient for $A$ to be finitely generated as a $k$-algebra.  Necessity: finitely generated as a module implies finitely generated as an algebra, and finitely generated over finitely generated is finitely generated.  Sufficiency: apply Noether normalization as suggested in the responses below (e.g. Eisenbud, Thm. 13.3).  This has an evident generalization to any finite Krull dimension.

Comment: +1 for catching my error, Prof. Clark.

Answer (score 2):

Dear Amitsur,

It might help you to think geometrically.  For example, $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is the ring of functions
on a hyperbola $xy = 1$, and the projection from this hyperbola to the line $x = y$ is a finite projection.  This corresponds to the fact that $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is finitely generated as a module over $k[x  + x^{-1}].$ (If we write $f = x + x^{-1}$, then $x^2 - f x +1 = 0$
and $x^{-2} - f x^{-1} + 1 = 0$.)

Answer (score 0):

This is always the case, by Noether normalization. For a proof, see for examlple, Eisenbud - "Commutative algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry" - Theorem 13.3.

Edit: this is false, one need a finiteness assumption. See comments below.

Comment: It's clearly not always the case, because A could be L[T], a polynomial ring in one variable over a field L which is a huge algebraically closed field and a transcendental extension of k

Comment: you are right off course. My mistake, I misread the question.

Comment: This is incorrect.  If $A$ is a finitely generated module over $k[t]$, then in particular $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, hence a Hilbert-Jacobson ring.  The Laurent series ring $k[[t]]$ is a PID (and not a field) with only finitely many prime ideals, hence not Hilbert-Jacobson: see e.g. Section 8 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from a direct generalization of the Noether normalization lemma.  It is covered in these [notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supNoeth.pdf) from Mel Hochster.  These notes prove it in a pretty general form (when the base ring is only an integral domain rather than a field).

Edit: <del>A sufficient condition is that the algebra is finitely generated, but it is clearly not necessary.</del>

Edit 2: I misread the question.  I thought he was asking if A is finitely generated over some polynomial algebra (including infinitely generated polynomial algebras).

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll check the sources you gave me. So, the Laurent polynomial ring A=k[x,x^{-1}] must be finitely generated k[f]-module for some f in A then. This is kind of strange, isn't it?

Comment: See the comments above.  This is incorrect (note: being finitely generated over k is clearly necessary.)

Comment: Dear Amitsur, perhaps it seems less strange if you realize that you can take f=x+x^{-1} and that x then satisfies the equation x^2-fx+1=o, so that 1 and x generate A as a k[f]-module .

Comment: lol, of course! Thanks Georges Elencwajg. I guess I need to get some rest. Thank you all for your useful comments. 